# Dart - How do you write a test against a function that calls exit()?

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

I want to test a function that calls exit.

Basicly, I have a console application, that asks the user if he is sure that he wants a directory to be overwritten. When the users answers "No", the directory won't be overwritten, and the program should exit.

```
promptToDeleteRepo() {
  bool okToDelete = ...
  if(okToDelete) {
    deleteRepo();
  } else {
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

So I want to test that if the user answers "No", that the program really exits. But if I test this, my test runner exits.

In python I seem to be able to do something like:

```
with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
    promptToDeleteRepo();
```

Is there something like this in Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject a custom `exit` function during the tests.

```
import 'dart:io' as io;

typedef ExitFn(int code);

ExitFn exit = io.exit;

promptToDeleteRepo() {
  bool okToDelete = ...
  if(okToDelete) {
    deleteRepo();
  } else {
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

and in your test :

```
int exitCodeUsed;
mylib.exit = (int code) {exitCodeUsed = code};
mylib.promptToDeleteRepo();
```

A better solution whould have to use [zones](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/zones/) but there doesn't seem to be possible to handle `exit`. It could be worth to [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new).

Answer (score 2):

One option that comes to my mind is to run the code you want to test in a new process `Process.run()` or `Process.start()` and check the exit code at the end. You can use stdin/stdout to communicate with the process (send keyboard input, read output)

Comment: Just saw that Jerweb suggested the same in Slack :)